# Spark Mllib .toBlockMatrix results in matrix of 0.0

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, block

I am trying to create a block matrix from a input data file. I have managed to get the data read from the data file and stored in IndexedRowMatrix and CoordinateMatrix format correct.

When I use .toBlockMatrix on the CoordinateMatrix the result is a block matrix containing only 0.0 with the same dimensions as the CoordinateMatrix.

I am using version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.0

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.CoordinateMatrix
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRow
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Transpose");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val dataRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/data/data.txt").map(line => Vectors.dense(line.split(" ").map(_.toDouble))).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
//Format of dataRDD is RDD[(Long, Vector)]

val rows = dataRDD.map{case(k,v) => IndexedRow(k,v)}
//Format of rows is RDD[IndexedRow]

val mat: IndexedRowMatrix = new IndexedRowMatrix(rows)
val coordMat: CoordinateMatrix = mat.toCoordinateMatrix()
val blockMat: BlockMatrix = coordMat.toBlockMatrix().cache()
```

The data file is just simply two columns by sixty rows of integers.

```
140 123
141 310
310 381
480 321
... ...
```

Update:

I've done some investigating and have discovered that the groupByKey function is not working correctly, which is what is preventing the BlockMatrix from being formed correctly. I still however do not know why groupByKey, join, and groupBy are not working and always returning an empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by removing the lines of code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Transpose")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I found the answer in the below linked page in a comment by Farzad Nozarian,

[Unable to count words using reduceByKey((v1,v2) => v1 + v2) scala function in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675735/)

As a side-note this might help people who are getting empty results for .groupByKey, .reduceByKey, .join, etc.